# Создание динамической библиотеки

Tags: c#, c++

Нужно написать какой-то код на С++ (в частности - функцию), а потом эту функцию использовать в другом проекте, реализованном уже на C#. Как это делается? Все примеры в интернете даны на одном языке, а как сделать так, чтобы функция, написанная на С++ работала в проекте на C#? Ответы, которые уже есть на форуме по данному вопросу, не помогли

Comment: Как вариант использовать `c++/cli`, после подключить к проекту `c#` и использовать управляемые классы.

Comment: @Birdy, можно подробнее, пожалуйста

Comment: @IWProgrammer, прочитайте про `c++/cli` это все тот же "c++" (в кавычках) [.NET Programming with C++/CLI (Visual C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68td296t.aspx). К примеру у меня так реализован медиаплеер `libvlc`, точнее обертка над ним.